# linking anchor text to open a specific tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tabs

I don't know why it didn't work. I have anchor text to link for the Nav tab.
I want when I click the anchor text the specific navtab should open.
like when I click tabtwo an anchor. the tab2 a navtab should open, btw they are with the same page. Is there someone how it works? please help me.

I am new to JavaScript. I don't know where I start in coding a JavaScript

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ISTAU.png)

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container" style="margin-top: 100px;">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
      <div>
        <!--bib-->
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <a id="tabs1" href="#tabone">tabone</a>
          </div>

          <div class="col-md-4">
            <a id="tabs2" href="#tabtwo">tabtwo</a>
          </div>

          <div id="tabs3" class="col-md-4">
            <a role ="tabpanel" href="#tabthree">tabthree</a>
          </div>
        </div>
    
        <!-- Nav tabs -->
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="list-item" role="tablist">
          <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#tabone" aria-controls="tabone" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">tab1</a></li>
          <li role="presentation"><a href="#tabtwo" aria-controls="tabtwo" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">tab2</a></li>
          <li role="presentation"><a href="#tabthree" aria-controls="tabthree" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">tab3</a></li>
        </ul>

        <!-- Tab panes -->
        <div class="tab-content">
          <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="tabone">
            <h3>sample1</h3>
          </div>
          <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="tabtwo">
            <h3>sample2</h3>
          </div>
          <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="tabthree">
            <h3>sample3</h3>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you can only open a new tab or open a new named tab.

Comment: it is in the same page.

Comment: well then it is unclear what you want to do. if you are trying to implement tabs then you have to first make them actually look like tabs. using html and css. all js does is hide and reveal

Comment: This is not a javascript issue, there are ways to talk between windows with JS but what you're trying to do is simply not possible.

Comment: i have a picture of my project. i was trying like when i click an anchor text it the specific  nav tab and accordion will open.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go with a solution

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.userhref').click(function(){
    $('#list-item').find('li').find('a[href=' + $(this).attr('href') + ']').closest('li').addClass('active').siblings('li').removeClass('active');
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container" style="margin-top: 100px;">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
      <div>
        <!--bib-->
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <a class="userhref" id="tabs1" href="#tabone" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">tabone</a>
          </div>

          <div class="col-md-4">
            <a class="userhref" id="tabs2" href="#tabtwo" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">tabtwo</a>
          </div>

          <div class="col-md-4">
            <a class="userhref" id="tabs3" href="#tabthree" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">tabthree</a>
          </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Nav tabs -->
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="list-item" role="tablist">
          <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#tabone" aria-controls="tabone" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">tab1</a></li>
          <li role="presentation"><a href="#tabtwo" aria-controls="tabtwo" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">tab2</a></li>
          <li role="presentation"><a href="#tabthree" aria-controls="tabthree" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">tab3</a></li>
        </ul>

        <!-- Tab panes -->
        <div class="tab-content">
          <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="tabone">
            <h3>sample1</h3>
          </div>
          <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="tabtwo">
            <h3>sample2</h3>
          </div>
          <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="tabthree">
            <h3>sample3</h3>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You are missing `bootstrap.js` file. Have a look into the ordering of the CSS & JS files.

Since bootstrap uses jQuery, so you need to load `jQuery` first then `bootstrap`.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: thankyou sir. it help!! but the nav bar did'nt change. but the content of nav bar changed like what i want. almost there sir. :))

Comment: @anuarditucalan In the code snippet it's working as per your requirement.

Comment: yes sir it working in snippet i wondering why in my notepad did'nt work properly.

Comment: even in w3school i try to run your code but still did'nt work properly. when i click the tab1 the tabone nav bar did'nt change but the content change.

Comment: @anuarditucalan Did you copied the JavaScript code? I've updated the answer, have a look.

Comment: sir it run properly. hahaha. the only problem i put the javascript code at <head> it should put inside the body. thanks a lot sir!

Comment: @anuarditucalan not necessary, yourJavaScript code should work in the head section as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, if this is what you are looking for.

```
<div >
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="list-item" role="tablist">
     <li role="presentation" class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab1">Tab1</a></li>
     <li role="presentation"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab2">Tab2</a></li>
     <li role="presentation"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab3">Tab3</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
 <div class="tab-content">
    <div id="tab1" class="tab-pane active"> </div>
    <div id="tab2" class="tab-pane"> </div>
    <div id="tab3" class="tab-pane"> </div>
 </div>
```